# Eclipse install not sees java

Tags: 16.04, java, jdk, netbeans

I have downloaded JDK with NetBeans from Oracle and installed on my Ubuntu.
I have updated my `/etc/environment` with line:

```
JAVA_HOME=usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/
```

Have updated `.bashrc` with lines:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

and executed the command

```
source /etc/environment
```

And finally got java command in the console.

But when I tried to execute eclipse installer `eclipse-inst` I got an error that I suppose means my desktop doesn't see java:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

UPD:

Now my `/etc/environment` loolks:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/"
```

And `.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/
...
```

Still have java command in console, but eclipse installer still needs java. How to tel desktop where is java?

Comment: You missed a `P`, and added a `/` to `bin` please update your corrections so I know if it's a typo and not the actual entries

Comment: I have "P" in my file and I have tested both - with "/" and without - installer still needs java. Is there any rules when I need to use "/" at the end and when no?

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.bashrc` after update or close and open new terminal?

Comment: I do restart of whole system

Comment: I can run eclipse installer from terminal without problem, but still interesting why desktop can't see java

Comment: what desktop are we talking about here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70204/discussion-between-vico-and-george-udosen).

Answer (score 3):

Please change:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

To:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And this line in your `/etc/environment` file `JAVA_HOME="usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/"` should be `JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/"`. Missing `/` before `usr`!

Comment: This not helped. I have updated question body with more details